# querying one R data frame by matching multiple columns from a second data frame

Tags: r

Say I have a data set that describes the abundance of different species, at different sites, `d1`:

```
site <- c(1:5)
species1 <- c('A','A','B','C','A')
abundance1<- c(0.11,0.45,0.87,1.00,0.23)
species2 <- c('B','C','A','A','C')
abundance2 <- 1 - abundance1  
d1<- data.frame(site,species1,abundance1,species2,abundance2)
```

So, each site has two species, and there is an `abundance` column that describes the proportion of the total community each species represents.

I then have a second data set, `d2`, that describes some trait measurement of each species within a plot, for instance `weight`. So, species A in plot 1 may have a different observation of `weight` than species A in plot 2. The dataframe, `d2`, looks like this:

```
site<- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)
species <- c('A','B','A','C','B','A','C','A','A','C')
weight <- rnorm(10, 50,4)
d2<- data.frame(site,species,weight)
```

I would like to generate a column within `d1` that is the abundance weighted average of `weight`, using the `weight` data in `d2` such that each species within plot is assigned their unique observation of `weight` in the final calculation.

The expected output for the first entry of the new calculated vector would be the output of the function:

```
d1[1,3]*d2[1,3] + d1[1,5]*d2[2,3]
```

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: @mtoto I've fixed this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old school R. May be an easier way with other packages but this is straightforward `apply`.

```
d1$newvec <-    apply(d1, 1, function(x) 
                      d2[d2$site==x[1]&d2$species==x[2],'weight']*as.numeric(x[3]) + 
                      d2[d2$site==x[1]&d2$species==x[4],'weight']*as.numeric(x[5]))
```